# If h_n converges in measure to h, then does |h_n| converge in measure to |h|?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

If h_n converges in measure to h, then does |h_n| converge in measure to |h|?

My thoughts thus far are that because |h_n - h| >= |h_n| - |h|, we cannot conclude this about the absolute values of the sequence.

Comment: $||h_n|-|h||\leq |h_n-h|$.

Comment: Yes, but could you help explain why this shows that |h_n| converges in Measure to |h|?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, $||h_n|-|h||\leq |h_n-h|$. Hence if $||h_n|-|h||>\varepsilon$ then $|h_n-h|>\varepsilon$. Therefore there is an inclusion
$$ \{x:||h_n(x)|-|h(x)||>\varepsilon\}\subset \{x:|h_n(x)-h(x)|>\varepsilon\}$$
which implies that
$$ \mu(\{x:||h_n(x)|-|h(x)||>\varepsilon\})\leq \mu(\{x:|h_n(x)-h(x)|>\varepsilon\})$$

If $h_n\to h$ in measure, then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x:|h_n(x)-h(x)|>\varepsilon\})=0$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$, which then implies that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x:||h_n(x)|-|h(x)||>\varepsilon\})=0 $$
for all $\varepsilon>0$. Therefore also $|h_n|\to |h|$ in measure.

Comment: oh ok, i see. thank you